# need formula to find latest date from list of duplicated ID#'s

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates, formula

I have a tool where I put an ID # into a cell and it uses VLookups to fill in other information about sites on the table.  I need to add a cell that looks for that same ID# in column A of a different table with several duplicates and returns the most recent date associated with that ID #.

if possible I'd need a 2nd version of it that references a 3rd cell.

the iD#s are construction sites.  The Dates are site visits and the third item would be reason for visit.  IE power inspection, pre-construction etc.
so the finished table would find the Site ID# and give me the most recent date it was visited and the adjoining cell would tell me the reason it was visited.

I have not used formulas like this in some time.  I've tinkered with some but got nowhere.

its a formula I need.

I'm trying to create two columns in a table that gives me the most recent date a site was visited and the reason it was visited.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Google for Array Formulas in Excel. You can create an Array Formula that gets the max date in a range where ID = something. Here in SO are several examples, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125589/excel-array-formula-for-max-date/55126130#55126130

Comment: Also, if you have Excel 2016 or 365, check [MAXIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). In Excel, dates are numbers, so the latest date is the max number in a range.

Comment: I have this working:=IFERROR(MAXIFS('Past Walks2'!D:D,'Past Walks2'!A:A,'3.22 Site Walk Schedule'!D7),"")

Comment: Please, do not poste formulas on comments. Edit your question and update it with your progress. Also, I think a data example would help (the input you have and the expected output you want to get)

Comment: I think I need a two column look up for the 2nd cell.